# Mockito - verify a method call with expected argument but ignore certain fields

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am mocking a class called EmailSender which has a method `sendEmail()` that takes in an argument of class Email. I am trying to verify that my `mockEmailSender` will call the `sendEmail` function once with the expected `Email` class as such: `verify(mockEmailSender, times(1)).sendEmail(expectedEmail)`

```
class Email {
   String title;
   List<String> receipients;
   EmailBody body;
}
```

I am initializing the expected Email object like the follow `Email expectedEmail = Email.builder().setRecipients(//example list).setTitle("Test title").setBody(//make this not matter)`

How can I make this work while ignoring the body field? So I just want to check that the `sendEmail()` method is called using `expectedEmail` and that the `expectedEmail` has all of the fields as set by me while ignoring certain fields such as the body field that I do not wish to explicitly set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ArgumentMatchers.refEq`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#refEq-T-java.lang.String...-) matcher can help you easily ignore fields you don't care about:

```java
verify(mockEmailSender, times(1)).sendEmail(refEq(expectedEmail, "body"));
```

Comment: Can be used only if equals() is not implemented. If implemented use argThat.